# What does this mean? 'last n row'?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

What does this mean? 'last n row' ???

The reason why I need to know about 'last n rows' is because I am looking at setting up a FTP or SFTP to feed into my google sheet with each new data feed going after the previous data feed. leadbridge https://leadsbridge.com/documentation/ftp-sftp/google-sheets/ looks like it can do this, but in it's instruction it says 'collect only last N rows and I don't know what that means

Comment: Without looking, i would guess it means it's a function to collect the last number of rows that the user specified. So if you wanted the last 12 rows, replace N with 12. Just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

"Last N rows", not "Last N row", is using the mathematical concept of a variable `N` to say that you're going to "Collect only last N rows" of the sheet.

So, if you want 10 rows then replace `N` with `10` and you'll get the "last 10 rows".

Answer (score 0):

`last n` of something is mostly english math concept where you substitute `n` with any number you need to work with and as an expression, it can be used in various fields:

- last n rows
- last n days
- first n hours
- n apples
- etc.

if something is labeled with `n` then it is safe to assume you can substitute `n` with the number of your choice. in non-english countries, this expression can differ or it could be completely missing. (for example in my country the expression is `last x rows`)